# send file to printer from mac - java

Tags: java, macos, file

I wrote this small java program to send a file directly to a printer to be printed:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  
{
    try{
        InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\example.txt"));  
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(new File("\\\\path\\printer\\example.txt"));  

        // Transfer bytes from in to out  
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024];  
        int len;  
        while ((len=in.read(buf)) > 0) {  
           out.write(buf,0,len);  
        }  
        in.close();  
        out.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this works fine in windows, but not on Mac.

Any idea how can I do the same on Mac Os X?

Note that I tried to copy a file from one folder to another locally in the mac machine and works, but not when FileOutputStream get a remote folder.

Comment: Well C:\\example.txt won't work on a mac for starters. Have you tried a path like /tmp/example.txt?

Comment: As I said, I tried to copy a file in the local mac machine and worked, so yes, I tried a path of that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *file shares*, you can translate a UNC path like that to something like

```
smb://server/folder/file.txt
```

But I don't believe this is possible for printer shares; I think it's more involved. An SMB printer URL looks like

```
smb://username.password@workgroup/computer/printer
```

In any case, `FileOutputStream` cannot write to URLs, so there's no way to make things work this way.

Java has a whole printing API which is not so terribly hard to use; if you master it, you can write a portable program which solves this problem on every platform.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you think would be possible to implement the same using jcifs? With that you can have something like

SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://host/c/My Documents/somefile.txt", auth);

I tried using that, but the authentication does not work when using guest - the example I posted above uses no authentication at all. There is a small example here: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/